# PDAL: filters.outlier: Unexpected argument 'extract'

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am trying to filter outliers from a point cloud with using [filters.outlier](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.outlier.html).
PDAL is version 1.5 and is installed and used through Docker in ubuntu 14.04.

When running my pipeline script

```
{
    "pipeline": [
        "data/input.ply",
        {
            "type": "filters.outlier",
            "method": "statistical",
            "extract": "true",
            "multiplier": 3,
            "mean_k": 8
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.ply",
            "filename":"data/output.ply"
        }
    ]
}
```

with docker

```
docker run -v /home/niels/data:/data pdal/pdal:1.5 pdal pipeline /data/filter.json
```

this error occurs

```
PDAL: filters.outlier: Unexpected argument 'extract'.
```

The `extract` argument is described in the docs and in [tutorials](https://www.pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/denoising/denoising.html).

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Going back to version 1.4 it works just fine. `docker pull pdal/pdal:1.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs just need to be updated at this point. The [release notes](https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/releases/tag/1.5.0) for PDAL v1.5 describe the change in behavior.

This pipeline should work for you in PDAL v1.5.

```
{
    "pipeline": [
        "data/input.ply",
        {
            "type": "filters.outlier",
            "method": "statistical",
            "multiplier": 3,
            "mean_k": 8
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.range",
            "limits": "Classification![7:7]"
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.ply",
            "filename":"data/output.ply"
        }
    ]
}
```